# Java Stacks/Cannot Find Logic Error

Tags: java

For my CS class, I had to create a boolean function isBalanced(String x) that takes a string and evaluates the amount of brackets/parentheses and returns true if the brackets match up to its pair (e.g; { is a pair of }, ( is a pair of ), [ is a pair of ], etc.). The function would return true if the brackets correctly matched up, false if otherwise. For clarification, MyStack() is my own implementation of the Java stack interface if you are wondering what that Object was.

Examples of how the code would work and return:

{A(B[C])D} would return true.

{A(B[C)]D} would return false.

The problem in my code is a logic error. For some reason, my function is returning true if there is a missing bracket, which should return false.

{A(B)C would return false, but my code reads it as true. Do you have any solutions that would help my code work properly? Thanks!

Balancer.java

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String x) {
    MyStack<String> stack = new MyStack();

if (x.substring(0,1).equals("}")  || x.substring(0,1).equals(")") || x.substring(0,1).equals("]")) {
    return false;
}
for (int i=0; i<x.length(); i++) {
    if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("{") || x.substring(i,i+1).equals("(") || x.substring(i,i+1).equals("[")) {
        stack.add(x.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("}") || x.substring(i,i+1).equals(")") || x.substring(i,i+1).equals("]")) {
        if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("}") && stack.peek().equals("{")) {
            stack.pop();
        } else if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals(")") && stack.peek().equals("(")) {
            stack.pop();
        } else if (x.substring(i,i+1).equals("]") && stack.peek().equals("[")) {
            stack.pop();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

This file, labeled Main.java, is just a tester. I have omitted the other cases where the code works. The reason why the function should return false is that there is a missing } which should be at the end, but there is none, yet my function returns true for some reason.

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    String test4 = "{AA[B(CDE{FG()T})V]";
    System.out.println("Missing final close (empty stack case)");
    System.out.println("Should be false, is: " + Balancer.isBalanced(test4));   // does not work        
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `return stack.isEmpty();` I would have expected - not even reading the code. Because all open brackets must be closed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of conditions that only pop the stack if a matching pair of brackets are found. I think you're overcomplicating things - if an opening bracket is found, push it to the stack. If a closing parenthesis is found, pop the stack and make sure that they match. E.g.:

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> CLODSE_TO_OPEN = new HashMap<>();
static {
    CLODSE_TO_OPEN.put(')', '(');
    CLODSE_TO_OPEN.put(']', '[');
    CLODSE_TO_OPEN.put('}', '{');
}

public static boolean isBalanced(String x) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i) {
        char c = x.charAt(i);
        if (CLODSE_TO_OPEN.containsValue(c)) {
            stack.push(c);
        } else if (CLODSE_TO_OPEN.containsKey(c)) {
            try {
                if (!CLODSE_TO_OPEN.get(c).equals(stack.pop())) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Stack#empty()` instead of wrapping the `Stack#pop()` call with a try-catch?

Comment: @Obicere Just a stylistic preference. You could definitely check `empty()` explicitly.